# How to vertically align two or more (side by side) elements in a div?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align two elements with different heights in a div:

```
<div class="footer-icons">
    <div id="footer-twitter">
         <img src="images/twitter.png" width="40" alt="">    
    </div>
    <div id="footer-fb">
         <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/user" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="160" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The twitter div has a height of 40px, and the fb div has a height of 20px. What is currently happening is the fb div is vertically centered with the bottom edge of the twitter image. Here's the CSS:

```css
.footer-icons {
    padding-top:40px;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#footer-twitter {
    display:inline-block;
}

#footer-fb {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both the FB & Twitter elements are pushed down 40px by the parent's padding-top.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Put the vertical align on the inner divs

```
#footer-twitter{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#footer-fb{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: If second `<div>` is long enough, it will end below the image. How could we stop that?

Comment: Note that this is not CSS3 and *will* work on older browsers as long as you change your `div` elements to be `span` elements.

Answer (score 15):

`display: flex` is a pretty cool tool to have in your toolbelt. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is some helpful documentation to get you started with it.

Specifically in your case these properties would be useful:

`align-items:center` - this will vertically align the centers of all child elements

`justify-content:center` - this will horizontally center child elements within the parent container (not sure you want this or not, but may be helpful as well)

```css
.footer-icons {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top:40px;
    width:300px;
    margin: auto;
    
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-icons">
    <div id="footer-twitter">
        Center me  
    </div>
    <div id="footer-fb">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png" width="40" alt="">   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `display: flex; align-items: center;` in `.footer-icons` **CSS** will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.footer-icons {
    padding-top:40px;
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a `line-height` equal or greater than the bigger icon:

```
.footer-icons {
    ...
    line-height: 32px;
}
```