# Vertically align two side by side elements to each other

Tags: css, datatables

I have two elements side by side: a chart and a DataTable. The DataTable can change size from interacting with the page and the chart should change size when the window is resized. I want the shorter one to always centre itself with the taller one i.e. the current height of their containing div. I'd like it to be done in CSS only, if possible. This answer doesn't seem to work for me: [CSS - vertically align two or more (side by side) elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569980/css-vertically-align-two-or-more-side-by-side-elements-in-a-div);

I have the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg id="chart"></svg>
    <div id="dataTable"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#chart {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#dataTable {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle or something like that? Thanks

Comment: If the vertical-align property is not working as per the answer you refer to, would you consider using a table as your parent container instead of a div? Using `vertical-align: middle` on `td` elements works pretty reliably.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Would it be similar to add `display: table` to container and `display: table-cell` to the inner elements? This did not work. Does it have something to do with my height being a percentage for the #container?

Comment: You can't use float and inline block *at the same time*. I'd try removing the floats.

Comment: @Paulie_D if I remove the floats, they appear one under the other, not side-by-side.

Comment: That's a whitespace issue - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use float and inline block **at the same time**. I'd try removing the floats.

Then it's a matter of reseting the whitespace between the inline block elements.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 0;
  /* whitespace fix */
}
#container > * {
  font-size: 1em;
  /* reset font-size */
}
#chart {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
#dataTable {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="chart"></svg>
  <div id="dataTable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It aligns the table to the chart initially, but doesn't align the chart to the table when the table grows and the chart changes.

Comment: It works now! I forgot I was translating an inner element of the chart which seemed to interfere with that. I removed it and it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Flexbox for this. Align items will ensure the items stay centered.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yftaLtxr/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <svg id="chart">a</svg>
    <div id="dataTable">b</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

#chart {
    height:50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#f00;
}

#dataTable {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to center the chart after items are added to the DataTable.